# plot xarray Data array in pyGMT

Tags: python, python-xarray, pygmt

I have a grid (xyz) that covers the entire globe. The dataset consists of multiple columns containing, longitude, latitude, and several z-values. Here are the locations of each node:

[image]

Now I want to show any of the z-values using fig.grdimage. However, I am unable to construct a grid from my xyz-file.

I first read in the data using pandas. If I try to convert the dataframe to an xarray data array and plot it, I get the following error:

```
array = data.to_xarray()
fig = pygmt.Figure()
fig.basemap(region="d", projection="N12c", frame=True)
fig.grdimage(grid=array)
fig.coast(shorelines="0.5p,black")
fig.show()
```

"array" gives the following output:

```
Dimensions:    (index: 16200)
Coordinates:
  * index      (index) int64 0 1 2 3 4 5 ... 16194 16195 16196 16197 16198 16199
Data variables: (12/14)
    LONG       (index) float64 -179.0 -179.0 -179.0 -179.0 ... 179.0 179.0 179.0
    LAT        (index) float64 -89.0 -87.0 -85.0 -83.0 ... 83.0 85.0 87.0 89.0
    ELEVATION  (index) float64 2.965e+03 2.915e+03 ... -3.822e+03 -3.392e+03
    MOHO       (index) float64 -3.888e+04 -3.888e+04 ... -1.457e+04 -1.457e+04
    LAB        (index) float64 -1.2e+05 -1.2e+05 ... -1.245e+05 -1.245e+05
    RHO_C      (index) float64 2.851e+03 2.851e+03 ... 2.806e+03 2.806e+03
    ...         ...
    BOTTOM     (index) float64 -4.1e+05 -4.1e+05 -4.1e+05 ... -4.1e+05 -4.1e+05
    GEOID      (index) float64 -0.81 5.01 4.78 0.15 ... 3.28 3.42 1.52 -0.73
    FA         (index) float64 0.82 38.25 36.06 -17.35 ... 6.77 13.84 3.85 -2.68
    G_zz       (index) float64 0.01 0.33 0.22 -0.08 ... 0.07 0.12 0.04 -0.0
    G_xx       (index) float64 0.04 -0.1 -0.1 -0.02 ... -0.12 -0.1 -0.06 -0.04
    G_yy       (index) float64 -0.12 -0.23 -0.12 0.1 ... 0.05 -0.02 0.02 0.04
16200 16200 16200
```

However, I don't know how to specify which z-value of array I would like to show. The result is that GMT does not recognise the data type for grid.

I have extract the lon, lat and z-value columns and I tried to use pygmt.xyz2grd and pygmt.sphinterpolate to construct a grid, but that doesn't seem to work either. I'm convinced this should be very simple, but the pyGMT documentation (nor ChatGPT) provide a straightforward solution.

I have also tried using matplotlib's basemap (different projection):

```
map = Basemap(projection='ortho',lat_0=15,lon_0=160,resolution='l')     # Orthographic map centred on Western Pacific
map.drawcoastlines(linewidth=0.25)
clevs = np.linspace(0,70)
map.contourf(data.LONG, data.LAT, data.LAB, clevs, tri=True, latlon=False)
plt.title("")
plt.show()
```

However, this yields the following error:

```
<ipython-input-39-0a19769f6fd0>:5: UserWarning: The following kwargs were not used by contour: 'tri'
  map.contourf(data.LONG, data.LAT, data.LAB, clevs, tri=True, latlon=False)
```

Is there anyone that could help me?
Many thanks in advance,
Thomas

Comment: Can you show the output of `array`? Matplotlib and Cartopy is not an option?

Answer (score 0):

An input file with different columns (lon, lat, z_value1, z_value2, ...) can be passed directly to [`pygmt.xyz2grd`](https://www.pygmt.org/v0.9.0/api/generated/pygmt.xyz2grd.html) to create a PyGMT-ready grid. The columns, which should be used for lon, lat, and z-value can be selected via the `incols` parameter.
It is also possible to read the file first into a pandas DataFrame. A conversion to a xarray DataArray is not necessary.

This grid can then be plotted using [`pygmt.Figure.grdimage`](https://www.pygmt.org/latest/api/generated/pygmt.Figure.grdimage.html#pygmt.Figure.grdimage). Select the colormap via the `cmap` parameter.

Maybe this general code example can serve as an orientation.

*Input data*:
Please copy/paste it into a txt file named "test_data.txt", as it seems not possible to upload a txt file.

```
lon lat z_value1 z_value2
1 2 12 458
5 4 25 265
8 3 24 123
7 4 45 234
2 5 21 401
3 1 78 201
4 7 63 310
2 8 16 520
7 6 23 275
```

*Code example*:

```py
import pandas as pd
import pygmt


# Read data in pandas DataFrame
data_df = pd.read_csv("test_data.txt", sep=" ", header=0)

# Make PyGMT-ready grid from data
grid_test = pygmt.xyz2grd(
    #data="test_data.txt",  # pass file (add # at beginning of header line in file) OR
    data=data_df,  # pass pandas DataFrame
    region="d",
    # lon | lat | z-value
    incols="0,1,3",  # input column, zero-based indexing
    spacing="150m",  # arc-minutes, adjust for your needs and data
)


# Create figure object
fig = pygmt.Figure()

fig.grdimage(
    region="d",
    projection="N12c",
    grid=grid_test,
    cmap="batlow",  # select colormap
)

fig.coast(
    shorelines="0.2p,gray",
    frame=True,
)

fig.colorbar()

fig.show()
#fig.savefig(fname="xyz2grd_grdimage.png")
```

*Output figure*:
[image]